# Setting Focus on a Tab

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a tab in a windows form called Wafer Map that has three sub-tabs. The First sub-tab is the called Map and has a Load and Skip button. I am trying to set the focus on the Wafer sub-tab on the Load button click. This is the following code I have tried to use.

```
Private Sub Load_Wafer_Layout_Map_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Load_Wafer_Layout_Map.Click
    Wafer_Info.Enabled = True
    Wafer_Info.Show()
End Sub
```

The Wafer_Info.Enabled = True is used to enabled all of the controls on the Wafer tab and works properly when the button is clicked. I have tried using .Focus() and .Show() to bring focus to the next tab but I am not have any luck getting to switch. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that worked for me is `Tab_WaferMap.SelectTab(1)`. Tab_WaferMap is my main tab and the 1 is the index of the sub tab I wanted to show

Answer (score 7):

Just set it:

```
tabControl.SelectedTab = yourTab
```

On the Tab Controls Tab Pages, just ensure you name the tab you are attempting to reference.  Additionally, see *MSDN* [TabControl.SelectedTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab.aspx)

Comment: I just tried that get the following message: "Reference to a non-shared member requires and object reference."

Comment: @James, it says right on that page Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1 and Windows 7

Comment: Could not get you solution to work but I did figure out how to do it another way.

Comment: I had to do Application.DoEvents() right after and it worked

Answer (score 3):

I came across this thread as i was looking for a solution to my own focus issue.  I have a TabControl with many TabPages.  Each TabPage is set to auto scroll due to overflowing content.  The problem I ran into was the mouse scroll wheel would not function if the TabPage did not have focus.  Since there is not an event for each tab click it made setting focus to each TabPage a challenge.  It was not hard, but a challenge none the less.  So, here is my code (assuming auto scroll true).

On form load sets focus to main TabPage:

```
Private Sub frmParent_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    TabControl1.TabPages(0).Focus()
End Sub
```

Sets focus to current TabPage by getting the index then setting focus.
This is triggered by TabControl1.SelectedIndexChange event.

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim intTabIndex As Integer = TabControl1.SelectedIndex
    TabControl1.TabPages(intTabIndex).Focus()
End Sub
```

I hope someone find this useful.  It was very useful for me.

Joshua

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the [Selected Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex.aspx) of the tab (and sub-tab) using a (zero based) numeric value:

```
TabParent.SelectedIndex = 3
TabSub.SelectedIndex=2
```

Answer (score 0):

### One example to utilise

> Private Sub BtnGoprint_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnGoprint.Click
> If (txtggsett.Text.Length = "0") And (txtsunAR.Text.Length = "0") And (txtggsett.Text.Length = "0") Then

```
 MsgBox("Calculate first, then print," & vbCrLf & "DISABLED TO AVOID ERRORS", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "NESSUN CALCOLO")
        TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0
    Else
        TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 11
        Btnprint.Show()
        Btnprint.Focus()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).